# How ensure front-end and back-end object consistency of different programming language?

Tags: spring, angularjs, frontend, backend, consistency

we are working on a restful system. On the front-end side we use angular js and on the back-end side spring. Now one of the question is: how ensure that the exchanged object on the two side on the time remain consistent. I don't mean the realtime exchange of data that are persisted on DB, I mean the consistency of the programming objects.

Example: front-end sends a user objects with the fields: firstname and lastname, and the backend takes this object user with firstname and lastname.
In the future it can be that a field must change his meaning: for example firstname becomes name. Now the front-end can't speak with the backend. 
The best way to cover this is to write integration test: from front-end to DB. But is there not a better way to test only this "exchange-layer"?

One idea that i had is to put this objects (java class for backend and angular file) in a separate library, and make some control on the equals of the fields. But is this the best way to do that? Any idea how make this better?

Comment: I have the same problem with angular2 and PHP, did u find any solutions? I don't like integration test solution, cause now I have to create 3 similar classes (API + backend + frontend). Maybe it's possible to create classes in JSON format and then parse in php and angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case if you´re using Spring and modelAndAttribute, as soon as you changes one of the side client/server and an entity attribute name you will receive a BindingResult Exception from the framework. The only way to test this is by integration tests with selenium. Which will made the whole client/server transaction in the test to check that everything still working properly without any exception.

Read the documentation of how to integrated with Spring MVC  https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/26/spring-mvc-test-with-webdriver

Comment: Tank you Paul, I will try to use Web driver. And in the case that I have not Spring and angularjs? Is the very and only way Integration test?

Comment: No, you always can create you own integration test with other frameworks like JUnit. By the way Selenium is not a Spring technology, I post that link because I thought that you was using Spring Selenium is a stand alone technology http://docs.seleniumhq.org/